# on("keyup paste", function) copies data but does not update in Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery

The following **JS** works great. When I type in the `first_name` and `last_name` fields, the combined data is copied into the hidden `url_title` field.

When I update either of these fields, the updated data is also copied into the same `url_title field...in every browser **except Microsoft Edge**.

Any ideas for how I can remedy this would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#first_name , #last_name").on("keyup paste", function() {
        var str=$("#first_name").val() +  '_' +  $("#last_name").val();
        $("#url_title").val(str);
    });
    $("#first_name, #last_name").change(function() {
        $("#url_title").val($("#first_name").val() + "_" + $("#last_name").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks just fine to me. Tested in latest Edge. Maybe you're cached?  https://jsfiddle.net/plumwd/otmjzp6q/

Comment: Rats, I think I know what my problem is...I am using jquery.min.1.11.3.js.  Unfortunately for this site, I can't update the jquery version.